# Examining a C source code easily

Tags: c, ide

In Java, just by clicking the classes in Eclipse, I can go to that specific class being referenced. In C, how can I do that? As far as I can remember I wasn't able to do that in Eclipse. I had hard times manually finding where `extern`s are declared/defined etc.

Comment: Your question is compiler and operating system specific.

Comment: You will need to have the C Development Toolkit (CDT) installed in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
ctags
```

This is command line tool. You need to first create tags for your whole source code and then you can jump to defination of any function or variable.

---

In eclipce IDE

You can go its defination by using `F3` and come back using `Alt` + `<-`

If you do not want to use `F3` then press `Ctrl` and move curcer to that place and click on that...you will go to its defination.

Answer (score 2):

How to go to a certain place in the source code is IDE-specific and not related to the programming language, so your question doesn't make any sense.

Many C compilers support Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you do what you are asking for by placing the cursor on the item you are interested in, then press F3.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of the other replies (notably mentionning `ctags`), and if using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (i.e. `gcc`, `g++`, preferably version 4.8 or 4.9, etc....) you could use the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) plugin and [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

MELT enables you to work on the internal representations (such as [Gimple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMPLE)) of the GCC compiler.

In particular, MELT has powerful pattern matching facilities, and a command line interface to find particular Gimple patterns. So for example you could, with [a few command line arguments](http://gcc-melt.org/tutousemelt.html) to `gcc`, find all the calls to `malloc` with a constant argument bigger than 30 bytes. This requires working on the compiler internal representations (e.g. because of `sizeof` operators) and is not possible in a purely textual tool.

For finding occurrences of identifiers, you could use `grep`  or also the [`ack` perl tool](http://beyondgrep.com/).

The tools mentioned here (`ctags`, `grep`, [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), `ack`) are command line tools. It is up to you to configure or adapt your IDE (or editor like `emacs`) and/or your builder (like `make`) to invoke them.

<sup>Remember that compilers are command-line tools, at least on Linux</sup>

PS. I am the main author of MELT.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your project. Would like to try working on MELT too.